# Вложенный SQL запрос в Django

Tags: sql, python, django

Для подсчета количества зарегистрировавшихся пользователей по дням написал SQL-запрос:

```
SELECT count(*), date FROM (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(register_dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') FROM api_user
) AS date GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;
```

Как должен выглядеть запрос с использованием [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

def get_date(list_datetime):
    list_date = []
    for timestamp in list_datetime:
        _date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).date()
        date = time.mktime(date.timetuple())
        if not date in list_date:
            st_date = date # начало дня в сек
            end_date = date + 24*60*60 - 1  # конец дня в сек
            list_date.append(_date, st_date, end_date)
    return list_date

results = []
list_datetime = ApiUser.objects.order_by('register_dt').values('register_dt')
list_date = get_date(list_datetime)
for date, st_date, end_date in list_date:
    count = ApiUser.objects.order_by('register_dt').filter(register_dt__range=(st_date, end_date).count()
    results.append(date, count)
```

где

- `ApiUser` - ваша модель

Comment: Запрос должен вернуть два значения: дата и количество зарегистрированных. В Вашем случае вернется количество только по одному дню.

Comment: А! Извините, не верно понял вашего вопроса

Comment: @MichaelPak. Обновил

Comment: `register_dt` хранится в БД как `timestamp`. Необходимо как-нибудь перевести миллисекунды в дни.

Comment: @MichaelPak.

Простейший перевод, обновил

Comment: Наверное, этот перевод надо делать в `order_by`, иначе сгруппируется по миллисекундам.

Comment: @MichaelPak. 
Что-то я протупил, ведь если у вас timestamp- это это значит что у вас в поле хранится время и дата. Один из простейших вариантов это использовать уже работающий у вас sql и сделать запрос напрямую к базе без QuerySet

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30764/discussion-between-michaelpak-and-ivan-k).

Comment: @MichaelPak.
 обновлено

Comment: Не понял, зачем здесь нужен подзапрос. Можно обойтись без него, если с ним проблемы.

Comment: @msi.
Да в нем особо нет проблем, просто два запроса будет в базу. Он нужен для того чтоб можно было определить когда были зарегистрированы пользователи

Comment: @ivanK. Про 2 запроса не понял. Написал ответ.

Comment: @msi.
Вопрос сам заключен в том чтоб сделать через orm django

Answer (score 1):

Запрос синтаксически неверен. Так будет работать?

```
SELECT count(*), "date" FROM (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(register_dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "date" FROM api_user
) AS X GROUP BY "date" ORDER BY "date";
```

И без подзапроса на всякий случай:

```
SELECT count(*), TO_CHAR(register_dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') "date" 
FROM api_user
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(register_dt, 'yyyy-mm-dd') ORDER BY "date";
```